# interactive Augmented Reality 3D drawer

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, x3d, x3dom, metaio

I'm planning on doing an interactive AR application that will use a laser sensor (for distances), GPS technology to get a location, and then use compass/gyroscope for tracking 6DOF viewfinder
 movements. The user can choose from a number of ready-made 3D-models, and should be able to place them by selecting the desired location on the screen.
My target platform will be a 8"-handheld-device, running on windows8.

Any hints what would be the best AR-SDK or 3D-viewer to work with?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few 3D viewers that are working in the browsers. But most recently and most notably: [va3C viewer](http://va3c.github.io/viewer/va3c-viewer-html5/r7/va3c-viewer-r7.html)

It is webgl based app and doesnt require a server, so if your handheld device supports webgl, then you are good to go, however, whether it works on IE or not is questionable ;).

Although based on my experience and your usecase, I believe client side JS libraries do not provide enough access to the device's hardware. So you might have to serve the information like GPS, Gyroscope, from the server side, then gather this on the client using something like socket.io and then mash it up alongside the geometry.

I am trying to do something similar, although havent quite done it yet. Will keep you posted.

Another approach I am exploring is [X3DOM](http://x3dom.org), which gives the ability to write 3D data like XML alongside HTML, which is quite declarative and simple to pickup. X3DOM derives from X3D.

Tell me if you need more info.

Also, worth exploring for its motion abilities, is [Robot Studio](http://new.abb.com/products/robotics/robotstudio), which is a desktop app with SDK.